# Initializing a C++ array when length unknown until runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization

New to C++.  Working with: GCC C++ Compiler; Eclipse Neon (4.6.0); OS X Sierra

I have a program with an object type `ArrangementNode`, one member of which is an array of ints called `occupiedArray`. I do not know how many ints `occupyArray` needs to hold until runtime, so I want the size of `occupiedArray` to be an int variable with a value determined at runtime.  But, the compiler will not let me initialize the array with a variable size: `error: fields must have a constant size: 'variable length array in structure' extension will never be supported`.

This has to be a common need in C++.  How should I be approaching this?

Comment: use `std::vector`

Comment: If you don't know the required size in advance, you don't need an initialized array either. Just in the moment the array is used (i.e. some value is added) the array[i] "cell #i" is filled. If you need to read the array instead of writting on it, then you have previously added some values, don't you?. A novice approach is to use a fixed size you do know will always enough.